# Table listing the comparison of each record in other table

Tags: c#, sql

I want to create a table listing the comparison of each record in a table with every other record on basis of particular columns :

Example :

```
id | web        | author | book        | isbn   | pub 
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | www.a.com  |  sam  |  sams book   | 12345  |  sams pub
2  | www.b.com  |  ram  |  rams book   | 54321  |  rams pub
3  | www.c.com  |  sam  |  rams book   | 67891  |  tams pub
4  | www.b.com  |  ram  |  gams book   | 65644  |  gams pub
5  | www.a.com  |  sam  |  sams book   | 11111  |  xyzs pub
6  | www.c.com  |  tam  |  tams book   | 22222  |  abcs pub
7  | www.c.com  |  tam  |  tams book   | 33333  |  pqrs pub
```

So I want to create table with the comparision result of each record with every other record
on columns web,author,book

Result Table should be : (result weight is addition of web+author+book weight)

```
sorceRow|destRow| web   | author | book |  result weight
--------------------------------------------------------
 1     |   2    |    0  | 0      | 0    |      0
 1     |   3    |    0  | 1      | 0    |      1 
 1     |   4    |    0  | 0      | 0    |      0
 1     |   5    |    1  | 1      | 1    |      3
 1     |   6    |    0  | 0      | 0    |      0
 1     |   7    |    0  | 0      | 0    |      0
 2     |   3    |    0  | 0      | 1    |      1
 2     |   4    |    1  | 1      | 0    |      2
 2     |   5    |    0  | 0      | 0    |      0
 2     |   6    |    0  | 0      | 0    |      0
 ...
 6     |   7    |  1    | 1      | 1    |      3
```

What is fastest way to get this result in SQL Server script as well as in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a non-equijoin and lots of comparisons.  The following is the standard SQL method:

```
select t1.id as sourceRow, t2.id as destRow,
       (case when t1.web = t2.web then 1 else 0 end) as Web,
       (case when t1.Author = t2.Author then 1 else 0 end) as Author,
       (case when t1.Book = t2.Book then 1 else 0 end) as Book,
       (case when t1.ISBN = t2.ISBN then 1 else 0 end) as ISBN,
       (case when t1.pub = t2.pub then 1 else 0 end) as pub
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.id < t2.id;
```

Note that the comparisons would be a little more complicated if the columns could contain `NULL` values, but your sample data doesn't have any.

Comment: +1 I like your answer more than mine. It even made me think whether my answer is correct but I can't find flaws in it.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for help.This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @d_z . . . Your solution almost the same.  In fact, I had first considered using a `cross join`, but then decided that `join` better conveyed the action.  The `if`s are unnecessary, and I'm not familiar with `==` in MySQL, so I think you mean just `=`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, you're right of course, those were supposed to be '='. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Basically CROSS JOIN of the table on itself will do that multiplication [Cross Join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
As for comparison, it depends on the DB server you use - case or iif().

```
select
    l.id as sourceRow,
    r.id as destRow,
    iif (r.web = l.web, 1, 0) as web,
    iif (r.author = l.author, 1, 0) as author,
    ....
from T1 l
cross join T1 r
where l.id < r.id
```